# Dirichlet series expansion?

Tags: analysis, generating-functions

When an analytic function $f(x)$ is given, we can easily obtain the coefficient of $x^n$ in a power series expansion of it. I'd like to know if there exists something similar for Dirichlet series. Is there a systematic way to get the coefficient of $n^{-x}$ when a function $f(x)$, if it can be represented as a Dirichlet series, is given?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be found in Apostol's book. Given $D(s) := \sum_{n \geq 1} f(n) / n^s$, we can extract $f(n)$ by performing the integral for $x \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and any $\sigma > \sigma_D$ the abscissa of convergence for the series as
$$f(x) = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{T} \int_{-T}^{T} D(\sigma+\imath t) x^{\sigma+\imath t} dt.$$